# программа вызывает не тот метод в C#

Tags: c#

я новичок в языке C#, и столкнулся с такой проблемой, когда пытался написать тестовую программу для проверки своих навыков. Суть проблемы такова - считывая клавишу из *Console.Readkey()*, находясь при этом в *Commands.CmdsAlloc()*, я пытаюсь получить поле *Key*. Затем, с помощью оператора switch, программа должна определить - какая конкретно клавиша была нажата с клавиатуры. Однако, вся проблема в том, что нажимая на клавишу 1(Как я понимаю, программа её воспринимает как *ConsoleKey.D1*) вызывается не метод HumanCmds.HumanMenu() как должен, а, собсна, вызывается абсолютное ничего. а Нажав на клавишу 2(*ConsoleKey.D2*) вызывается не *WorkWithFile.SourceMain()*, а *HumanCmds.HumanMenu()*. Кто может помочь разобраться в этой ситуации?

Прилагаю ниже код всей программы. Приветствую любую критику :)

**MainControl.cs**

```
using System;
using HumanFactory.cmds;

namespace HumanFactory
{
    class MainControl
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Добро пожаловать на фабрику!");
            Commands.CmdsAlloc();
        }
        public static void Quit()
        {
            Console.Write("Введите что-нибудь для выхода... ");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

**Commands.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace HumanFactory.cmds
{
    public class Commands
    {
        static List<string> phrases = new List<string>() { "1-фабрика человечков", "2-Работать с сохранениями", "0-выход" };
        public static void CmdsAlloc()
        {
            foreach (string i in phrases)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{i}");
            }
            ConsoleKeyInfo inputed = Console.ReadKey();
            ConsoleKey choice = inputed.Key;
            Console.Write("\n");
            switch (choice)
            {
                case ConsoleKey.D0:
                    MainControl.Quit();
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.D1:
                    HumanCmds.HumanMenu();
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.D2:
                    WorkWithFile.SourceMain();
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Неизвестная комманда...");
                    break;
            }
            CmdsAlloc();
        }
    }
}
```

**HumanCmds.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace HumanFactory.cmds
{
    class HumanCmds
    {
        static int numberOfHuman = 0;
        static List<HumanConcept> humans = new List<HumanConcept>();
        public static List<HumanConcept> HumanMenu(int value = 1)
        {
            if (value != 1)
            {
                Console.Write("Выберите действие:\n1-создать человечка\n2-просмотреть человечков\n0-выход");
                ConsoleKey choice = Console.ReadKey().Key;
                Console.Write("\n");
                switch (choice)
                {
                    case ConsoleKey.D0:
                        Commands.CmdsAlloc();
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.D1:
                        humans = createHuman();
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.D2:
                        checkHumans(humans);
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Ошибка...");
                        break;
                }
                HumanMenu();
            }
            return humans;
        }
        private static List<HumanConcept> createHuman()
        {
            List<string> data = new List<string>();
            HumanConcept chel = new HumanConcept();
            Console.WriteLine($"Создаём {numberOfHuman} человечка!");
            Console.Write("Введите имя человечка: ");
            data.Insert(0, Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Введите фамилию человечка: ");
            data.Insert(1, Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Введите возраст человечка: ");
            data.Insert(2, Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Какой пол?\n1-мужской, 2-женский: ");
            data.Insert(3, Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Является ли человечек гражданином?\n1-да, 2-нет: ");
            data.Insert(4, Console.ReadLine());
            data.Insert(5, numberOfHuman.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Начинаем обработку данных...");
            chel.WriteVars(data);
            humans.Add(chel);
            Console.WriteLine("Данные записаны успешно.\nЧекайте вторую функцию программы...");
            Console.ReadKey();
            return humans;
        }
        private static void checkHumans(List<HumanConcept> humans)
        {
            foreach (HumanConcept i in humans)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{i.NumberOfHuman}: {i.Name} {i.Surname}, возраст: {i.Age}, пол: {i.Gender}, гражданин ли: {i.Citizen}");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Human.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace HumanFactory
{
    public class HumanConcept
    {
        public int NumberOfHuman { get; private set; }
        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public string Surname { get; private set; }
        public bool Citizen { get; private set; }
        public int Age { get; private set; }
        public string Gender { get; private set; }

        public void WriteVars(List<string> data)
        {
            Name = data[0];
            Surname = data[1];
            if ((Convert.ToInt32(data[2]) > 0) && (Convert.ToInt32(data[2]) < 200)) {
                Age = Convert.ToInt32(data[2]);
            } else
            {
                Age = 0;
            }
            if (data[3] == "1")
            {
                Gender = "мужчина";
            } else
            {
                Gender = "женщина";
            }
            if (data[4] == "1")
            {
                Citizen = true;
            } else
            {
                Citizen = false;
            }
            NumberOfHuman = Convert.ToInt32(data[5]);
        }

    }
}
```

**WorkWithFile.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.Json;

namespace HumanFactory.cmds
{
    class WorkWithFile
    {
        public static void SourceMain()
        {
            List<HumanConcept> hmns = HumanCmds.HumanMenu(0);
            Console.Write("Введите название файла: ");
            string filename = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Выберите операцию:\n1-запись\n2-чтение\n0-назад");
            ConsoleKey choice = Console.ReadKey().Key;
            Console.Write("\n");
            switch (choice)
            {
                case ConsoleKey.D0:
                    Commands.CmdsAlloc();
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.D1:
                    fileWrite(filename, hmns);
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.D2:
                    fileRead(filename, hmns);
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Ошибка...");
                    break;
            }
        }
        private static void fileWrite(string filename, List<HumanConcept> humans)
        {
            using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(filename, true))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Начинаем запись в файл!");
                foreach (HumanConcept i in humans)
                {
                    string strToWrite;
                    strToWrite = JsonSerializer.Serialize(i);
                    file.WriteLine(strToWrite);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Запись завершена успешно!");
        }
        private static void fileRead(string filename, List<HumanConcept> humans)
        {
            using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(filename))
            {
                string readed = file.ReadLine();
                HumanConcept chel = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<HumanConcept>(readed);
                humans.Add(chel);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Проверь, что именно находится в `choice` сразу после ввода.

Comment: Добавте ваш Console screen в вводом и выводом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```csharp
public static List<HumanConcept> HumanMenu(int value = 1)
{
    if (value != 1) // вот здесь ошибка
    //...
}
```

Вы вызываете без параметра `HumanCmds.HumanMenu()`, а меню отобразится только если вызвать с параметром, например `HumanCmds.HumanMenu(0)` или поменяйте условие на `value == 1`.

**Помимо этого:**

У вас везде бесконечная рекурсия без возможности возврата, а выход у вас - это не выход, а вход в новую бесконечную рекурсию. Перепишите код на бесконечный цикл `while(true)`, корень зла как раз в переходах между рекурсиями, он вас путает заставляя приложение работать странным образом. И бессовестно забивает стек. Если очень долго потыкать менюшки, вы получите `StackOverflowException`.

**Пример**

```csharp
public static void CmdsAlloc()
{
    while (true)
    {
        foreach (string i in phrases)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{i}");
        }
        ConsoleKeyInfo inputed = Console.ReadKey();
        ConsoleKey choice = inputed.Key;
        Console.Write("\n");
        switch (choice)
        {
            case ConsoleKey.D0:
                return;
            case ConsoleKey.D1:
                HumanCmds.HumanMenu();
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.D2:
                WorkWithFile.SourceMain();
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Неизвестная комманда...");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

При этом `Main` можно модифицировать так

```csharp
public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Добро пожаловать на фабрику!");
    Commands.CmdsAlloc();
    Console.Write("Введите что-нибудь для выхода... ");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Большое вам спасибо! Я правда не думал, что в этом языке программирования устроено всё так, видимо, это осталось мне от питона))
Мир вам!